# Microsoft.MixedReality.QR is nonexistent despite NuGet installation

Tags: nuget, qr-code, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality

I am working on a project in MixedReality using mainly MRTK and its features. I found out that MRTK can use QR codes to read data, and I wanted to use it and try multiples ideas.

The problem is that, currently, is seems any QR feature is nonexistent in my project.

I Installed the NuGet package Microsoft.MixedReality.QR and its corresponding Microsoft.VCRTForwarders.14 package, as indicated in
https://localjoost.github.io/Reading-QR-codes-with-an-MRTK2-Extension-Service/

But anything I try in code, from my project, will tell me in the console window that the namespace could not be found, and all cascading items (properties, classes, functions) could not be found either, none of them.
It is weird since everything should be installed and up to date ( I verified this directly in Visual Studio and everything is there).

Any kind of help would be much appreciated, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

For Unity projects, you need to import [NuGet for Unity](https://github.com/GlitchEnzo/NuGetForUnity) to install Mixed Reality QR NuGet package. Meanwhile the tutorial you are referring is not an official document. Some types/classes are defined by the author and are not included in Microsoft.MixedReality.QR namespace.

Please refer to the new QR sample on https://github.com/yl-msft/QRTracking and all the C# API references are listed on [QR Code tracking API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/native/qr-code-tracking-cs-cpp#qr-code-tracking-api-reference)

Answer (score 0):

I've been developing an app that uses QRcode on the hololens as well. I ran into that issue before, and the console seemed to throw that error for me because I was using the wrong version of the MRTK services in the Microsoft Mixed Reality Feature Tool. I would recommend using version 2.6.1 for all your services. Do you by any chance have a problem where "QR tracking is not supported" for the Unity Project you are building?

Comment: For your own questions (for problems that you're facing), please, use the "Ask a question"  button instead put them in your “Answer”. Thanks for sharing your knowledge and help others with your answers.